# CSS/Flexbox overlapping with percentage padding

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Why are the li items overlapping, and poking out of the right side of the container ul? I thought flexbox was supposed to make this stuff easier? haha

I just can't seem to get items with percentage padding on the left-right to distribute correctly with flexbox. What am I not understanding?

Please see my [code pen](http://codepen.io/bradbice/pen/pklax) for an example.

I am using:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="" class="btn">Link Text 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="" class="btn">Link Text 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is the CSS(SCSS):

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    color: #3b3c43;
    border: 1px solid #3b3c43;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: .75em 15%;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: .85em;
    white-space: nowrap;
    &:hover {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #3b3c43;
    }
}
ul {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    outline: 1px dotted blue;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
li {
    outline: 1px dotted red;
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with flexboxes. You have white-space: pre there and some padding that's why you get the overlaps. Use box-sizing: border-box if you want the padding to be part of the width

Comment: Interestingly, running the code when the page load it doesn't work. However, if you remove the padding on the `a`, let it compile, then undo so it's back to the original and let it compile it works again. Same thing happens when just changing the percent value.

Comment: @onetrickpony I don't see why the whitespace: nowrap is a problem. Also, I usually do use box-sizing: border-box, however I don't see how that would make a difference wither, seeing as how this is flexbox? Why doesn't the whitespace declaration push the elements out, padding and all? Shouldn't it increase the width of the element?

Comment: I would say that the answer is to not use percentage paddings.